# Ошибка illegal memory reference

Tags: ассемблер

Выскакивает ошибка `illegal memory reference` в строке `cmp lenght,c`, не знаю почему.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

c       dw      0
string      db      81 dup(' ')
lenght          dw      0
count       dw      0
result      dw      0
count_check dw      0
sys_ch      db      10
menu    db      'Menu:',0,0dh,0ah
        db      '1. Console input',0,0dh,0ah
        db      '2. File input',0,0dh,0ah
        db      '3. Exit',0,0dh,0ah,'$'
outfile         db      'O.txt',0
intfile         db      'I.txt',0
endline     db          0dh,0ah,'$'
chose       db      0
Ero     db      'Error!Try again',0,0dh,0ah,'$'
handle      dw      ?       
flager      db      0
f_file      db      '----[file]$'   
buff        db      6 dup(' ')
    .code
    .486
    mov ax,@data    
    mov ds, ax
men:
    lea dx,menu
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
enterise:
    mov ah,ch
    mov ah,01h
    lea dx,chose
    int 21h
    lea dx,endline
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    cmp al,'1'
    je console
    cmp al,'2'
    je filein
    cmp al,'3'
    je ender
    lea dx,Ero
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp enterise

filein:
    mov ah,3Dh              
    xor al,al               
    lea dx,intfile         
    xor cx,cx               
    int 21h 
    jnc f1
    lea dx,Ero
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp ender
f1:
    mov handle,ax
    mov bx,ax               
    mov ah,3Fh              
    lea dx,string          
    mov cx,80
    int 21h 
    mov lenght,ax
    jnc f2
    lea dx,Ero
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp ender
f2:
    mov bx,ax
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx,handle   
    inc flager      
    int 21h           
    jnc continue                 
    lea dx,Ero
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp ender
console:
    xor dx,dx
    mov ah,ch
    mov ah,0ah
    lea dx,string
    int 21h
    mov al,string+1
    cbw
    mov bx,ax
    add bx,2
    mov lenght,bx
    mov string[bx],0
    mov string[1],0
    lea dx,endline
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    lea di,string
    add di,2
    lea si,string
    add si,2
    jmp continue
continue:
    xor cx,cx
    xor ax,ax
    xor bx,bx
    xor dx,dx
    mov cx,lenght
    lea di,string   
    lea si,string
    mov bx,di
    cld
    xor ax,ax
start:
        lodsb
    push    si
    mov count_check,0
    cmp lenght,c
    je  finish
    inc     c
    jmp short start_checking

start_checking:     
    cmp al,97
    jl  start
    cmp al,122
    jg  start
    jmp checking

next_letter2:
    loop checking2

checking:
    push cx
    mov cx,lenght
    mov dl,al
    jmp checking2

checking2:
    lodsb
    cmp al,'$'
    je ending
    cmp dl,al
    je change_string
    jne next_letter2 

change_string:
    inc count_check
    dec si
    mov string[si],0
    inc si
    jmp next_letter2
ending:
    pop cx
    cmp count_check,0
    jne count_plus
    je pre_start
count_plus:
    inc count
    jmp pre_start
pre_start:
    pop si
    dec si  
    mov string[si],0
    inc si
loop start

finish:
    cmp flager,0
    jne fileout
    mov ax,count
    xor cx,cx
    mov bx,10   
oil2:
    xor dx,dx
    div bx
    push dx
    inc cx
    test ax,ax
    jnz oil2    
    mov ah,02h
oi3:
    pop dx  
    add dl,'0'
    int 21h
    loop oi3
    jmp ender
fileout:    
    xor dx,dx
    xor si,si
    mov si,4
    mov ax,count
    mov bl,sys_ch
deletium:
    idiv bl
    add ah,30h
    mov buff[si],ah
    dec si
    xor ah,ah
    test ax,ax
    jnz deletium
    add ah,30h
    xor si,si
    xor di,di
    xor ax,ax
    xor bx,bx
    xor dx,dx
    xor cx,cx
    mov ah,3Ch             
    xor al,al                
    lea dx,outfile          
    xor cx,cx               
    int 21h 
    jnc f4
    lea dx,Ero
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h 
    jmp ender
f4:
    mov handle,ax
    mov bx,ax
        mov ah,40h
    lea dx,buff
    xor cx,cx
    mov cx,6
    inc cx
    int 21h
    mov ah,3eh
    mov bx,handle
    int 21h
    jmp ender
ender:  
    mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
end
```

Comment: И какая строка в этой портянке 123?

Comment: @insolor метод start строка там где cmp lenght,c ошибка)

Comment: Ок, причина ошибки - нельзя напрямую сравнивать две переменные в памяти. Достаточно было в вопросе саму строку написать, вместо всего кода.

Comment: @insolor гениально, не думал что настолько прям строгий язык)

Answer (score 0):

В данной строке:

```
cmp lenght, c
```

вы пытаетесь сравнить значений двух переменных в памяти. Напрямую это сделать нельзя, можно сравнить значение в памяти с числом или с регистром, но не со значением в памяти (т.е. нужно сначала сохранить значение одной из переменных в регистр, потом вторую сравнивать с этим регистром).